# This question should not have been migrated!

Tags: discussion

I don't know why but sometimes I have seen [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/361013/132000) like this being migrated the Arduino because they have the Arduino tag and has nothing to do it. This is actually a very poor question and should have been closed. I am not trying to pull a debate with the moderator but I feel this site should send less crap to Arduino section because It is already so full of crap.

Answer (score -9):

Looked to me like a valid question about Arduino and related libraries.  At least it got a technical comment on Arduino.SE .

**update:**

The question was tagged [arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino), although it wasn't about an actual Arduino, as it turned out.

In such cases, folks, please edit the question and remove the [arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) tag.
[Somebody has already done it for the question being discussed.  Thank you.]

Comment: But it's not even an Arduino-board, unless there is an unofficial port somewhere. http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/boards/lpc4088_exp_bb_bundle.php

Comment: @pipe  He had tagged it [tag:arduino], so it ought to be about some kind of Arduino board.

Comment: @NickAlexeev It is not, it is some NXP evaluation board. https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-based-processors-and-mcus/lpc-cortex-m-mcus/lpc4000-cortex-m4/mid-range-32-bit-microcontroller-mcu-based-on-arm-cortex-m4-core:LPC4088FBD208. So it should have been closed as unclear, because the question doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @Lundin  It reminds me of this thread: [Poor abused Arduino tag](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/poor-abused-arduino-tag)

Comment: Reminds me of https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/migration-guidelines-re-arduinos